# Problema ao conectar-se no XAMPP porta 80

Tags: php, xampp

Não importa quantas vezes eu dou Start ou Stop, ele fica me dando o mesmo toda vez, **problema na porta 80 e unable acess**, mas se aperto start e vou no barra de endereços do e coloco **localhost:8080** ele apareçe a tela inicial do **`xampp`** !

```
1:36:45 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
1:36:49 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
1:36:50 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
1:36:52 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 212)
1:36:52 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 5920)
1:36:52 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
1:36:53 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
1:36:53 AM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
1:36:53 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
1:36:53 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
1:36:53 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
1:36:53 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
1:36:53 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
1:38:22 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 6208)
1:38:22 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 5672)
1:38:22 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
1:38:22 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to stop MySQL (PID: 6536)
1:38:23 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
1:39:32 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
1:39:32 AM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
1:39:32 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
1:39:32 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
1:39:32 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
1:39:32 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
1:39:32 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
1:39:35 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
1:39:35 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
1:39:38 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to stop MySQL (PID: 6820)
1:39:38 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
1:39:38 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 7844)
1:39:38 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to stop Apache (PID: 7872)
1:39:38 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
1:39:42 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
1:39:42 AM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
1:39:42 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
1:39:42 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
1:39:42 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
1:39:42 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
1:39:42 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
```

O que está havendo ? Já dei STOP naquele "World Wide Web" e enfim.

Comment: Tens o `skype` aberto ?

Comment: A janela ou o processo no gerenciador ?

Comment: Acabei de ver aqui, nem o processo nem a janela está aberta!

Comment: Experimenta reiniciar o computador. Depois volta a inciar o xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algum programa já esta usando a porta 80.
Faz um *sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 80* e veja qual programa esta usando a porta. 
Pega o *PID* e faz *sudo kill <PID>*, no log que passou o PID era 4 exemplo: *sudo kill 4*
Pode ser o skype, ele costumava usar a porta 80, da pra mudar nas configurações.

Comment: Complementando a resposta, para desabilitar o uso da porta 80 pelo skype vá em  Ferramentas -> opções -> Avançado -> Conexão e desabilite a primeira checkbox.

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda, não era bem isso ou o skype ! Eu caçei um pouco aqui e descobri o que era, e vou responder a minha pópria pergunta, mais cliquei ai nos 2 como útil, porque realmente foi ! Mas era o erro em outra coisa, logo vou responder ela de uma forma bem estruturada ! Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim, no Control Panel do Xampp, clique em <<Config>> na aba <<Apache>>, mude a porta de 80 (que o Windows usa para teste do sistema), coloque 8080. Salve e de um start no apache de novo. Se carregou tudo ok, clique em <<Admin>> e terás a pagina no teu browse. Boa sorte!